# How do I implement the Side menu like the Todo iOS app?

Tags: ios, iphone, residemenu

I want to implement side menu in iOS app such that On swipe it first shows just the menu icons and on swiping more it shows the menu text as well. Similar to To Do iOS app.

Comment: use SWRevealVeiwController to do this

Comment: Thanks @anuk that helped me solve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use [InteractiveSideMenu](https://github.com/handsomecode/InteractiveSideMenu) library. It supports interactive opening/closing menu and supports following customization:

- Animation duration
- Visible content width
- Content scale
- Using spring animation with params customization
- Animation options like animation curve

You should use 3 basic ViewControllers for creating subclasses for implementing your side menu.

- `MenuContainerViewController` is a host for menu and content views
- `MenuViewController` is a container for menu view
- `MenuItemContentControlller` is a container for content that corresponds menu item

Answer (score 0):

Check https://www.cocoacontrols.com/ and make a search for 'side menu' or 'drawer'. There are many libs, maybe you find one useful.

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=drawer

To add the libraries to your project, you can use CocoaPods: http://cocoapods.com/ It's the easy way to integrate libraries to your project.

In the project that I'm working right now I use MMDrawerController https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/mmdrawercontroller--2

Answer (score 0):

I used [SWRevealViewController](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController) to implement the side menu like ToDo App.